# Xamarin.iOS/monotouch memory management

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I’m trying to understand the memory management needed in Xamarin.iOS.

In the following scenario, does **this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController** release the created UIViewControllers or
should I release them? If I need to do it, where should this be done?

Each letter represent a UIViewController)

A ( rootViewcontroller)

from A:

```
B b = new B()
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (b, true);
```

From B:

```
C c = new C()
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (c, true);
```

From C:

```
D d = new D()
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (d, true);
```

From D:

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you enable "Use Reference Counting Extension"?   This will take care of this for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this configuration. 
For now, though, the results I see in XCode Instruments Allocations are a bit strange, as I don't see any memory being released, even though there are certain objects I'm disposing explicitly and which in the previous configuration I've seen released.
I do have to mention that I'm far from being an expert with using XCode Instruments Allocations.

Comment: In my experience avoiding memory leaks when using Xamarin has been extremely difficult. Our app has a code path that more or less restarts the app from scratch, reconstructing all objects and forgetting about the old ones. But the old ones hang around in memory and I have spent a hundred hours trying to get rid of them. Only by Dispose()ing things and nulling references can I make any headway, but such tactics are liable to introduce bugs.